# Two curves in the same plot with a defined function

Tags: plotting

I have made a database of several rods which have several physical variables and the function below plots all those variables of just one rod.

```
plotZVsKey[data_, key_] := Block[{plotData},
 plotData = Transpose[{data["Z [m]"], data[key]}];
 ListLinePlot[plotData, 
  PlotTheme -> "Scientific", GridLines -> Automatic,
  GridLinesStyle -> Directive[
   {Gray, Dashing[Small], RGBColor["Gray"],Opacity[0.5]}
  ],
  FrameLabel -> {"Z [m]", key}, 
  PlotRange -> All, 
  Ticks -> Automatic
 ]
];

plotRodSection[dataRod_] := Map[
 plotZVsKey[dataRod, #] &, Drop[rodVar, 1]
];
```

And then I use that function to see all the plots(of the variables) from just one rod of the database

```
plotRodSection[RodDatabase[[1]]]
```

But now what I want to do is the same but to show the information of two rods in the same plot.
Tried Show but I need to make a distinction of colors.

Comment: `Show[plotRodSection[RodDatabase[[1]]], plotRodSection[RodDatabase[[2]]]]`?

Comment: does this give what you need:  `keys = {1, 2, 3}; plots = plotRodSection /@ RodDatabase[[keys]];
lines = Cases[Normal[#], _Line, Infinity] & /@ plots;
coloredlines = {#, #2} & @@@ Transpose[{colors, lines}];
options =  Sequence[AspectRatio -> 1/2, GridLines -> Automatic, 
   GridLinesStyle ->  Directive[{Gray, Dashing[Small], Gray, Opacity[0.5]}], 
   Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"Z [m]", keys}, PlotRange -> All];
Graphics[coloredlines, options]`?